# Can TPM2 NVM encrypt data?

Tags: uefi, tpm, edk2

I am trying to use the functions in Tpm2CommandLib to write data to TPM2 in EDK2. I have defined the index that I am going to write data to, using the DefineSpace function. I also did write the data to NVM but what I am curious is that if it is possible to encrypt data in TPM.

First I have done some research and found out that it isn't possible but in TPMA_SESSION structure there is encypt parameter. Does it mean that I can do encrypt data?

Comment: Do you want to store data in the TPM or do you want to encrypt data in a way that only the TPM can decrypt it?

Comment: I want the TPM to store the data encrypted.

Comment: You can seal a data blob with the TPM and move it into persistent memory but i would recommend to store it outside the TPM. There is not much storage in a TPM. The data in the NVM indices may not be encrypted, but the TPM has to be tamper proof and so the data is also save in the NVM index.

Comment: I understand your point. The reason why I am doing this is to better understand low level TPM programming. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

The TPMA_SESSION flags permit encryption on the connection (e.g. SPI bus) between the host and the TPM. They do not affect how the data is stored in TPM NV.

While you could encrypt the data before sending it to the TPM, applications generally trust the TPM to protect its NV.